# HERE Maps JS API v3: customize cluster marker's color

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I know that I could just easily override `nokia.maps.clustering.MarkerTheme.getColor` in version 2.5.x to customize **only** the color of the *cluster marker*, but it seems there's no easy way to do so in version 3.0.x.

I mean, there is this `H.clustering.ITheme` interface that I could implement, yet it feels like it is a real pain for hacking into the color property. This is what I code so far (only relevant code shown):

```
var defaultTheme    = clusteredDataProvider.getTheme(),
    customTheme     = {

        /**
         *
         * @implements {H.clustering.ITheme.getClusterPresentation}
         */
        getClusterPresentation: function (cluster) {
            var clusterMarker = defaultTheme.getClusterPresentation
                .call(defaultTheme, cluster);

            /*
             * TODO: Change the color property of the cluster marker.
             * Hmm. How am I supposed to best do it?
             */

            return clusterMarker;
        },

        /**
         *
         * @implements {H.clustering.ITheme.getNoisePresentation}
         */
        getNoisePresentation: function (noisePoint) {
            var noiseMarker = defaultTheme.getNoisePresentation
                .call(defaultTheme, noisePoint);

            return noiseMarker;
        }
    };
```

Does HERE Maps have a base SVG template of the cluster marker that I could make use of?

Comment: It might be easier to implement a custom theme with custome markers.

Comment: No, it won't make any easier for me since I have to create everything from scratch (I have to deal with the sizing, coloring, shadowing, texting, text positioning), while all I need is just to change the color. The resulting custom markers probably won't look as nice as the default ones either.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can make out in the compressed code of the mapsjs-clustering.js, there is a bit more logic in the default theme than just creating new markers for every cluster. What seems to happen is that the API renders an image for each possible icon on the fly using canvas elements and then keeps reusing (get/putImageData calls) that for each marker based on the weight of the cluster. Here's some things I am able to figure out on where they create the icons:

```
weight < 10     : size 28, color "118, 209, 0", textPosition { x: 11, y: 18 }
weight < 25     : size 38, color "255, 105, 0", textPosition { x: 13, y: 23 }
weight < 50     : size 38, color "240, 60, 0", textPosition { x: 13, y: 23 }
weight < 100    : size 38, color "181, 0, 21", textPosition { x: 13, y: 23 }
weight < 1000   : size 48, color "181, 0, 21", textPosition { x: 15, y: 28 }
weight > 1000   : size 66, color "181, 0, 21", textPosition { x: 20, y: 38 }
```

So, to change the color property, you'd pretty much have completely reverse engineer the icon drawing code and rewrite it. Not sure this is a worthwhile approach...

Comment: I voted up this answer because it pretty much gives me a hint for doing some workaround. Although it's not a very elegant solution, overriding (hardcoding) these values deep down in the library with the desired colors serves as a temporary solution for me. :-)