# HERE Maps JS API V3 - Clustering: how to get the default cluster icon

Tags: javascript, here-api

I've to customize only the noise icon, so I'm going to override only the `getNoisePresentation` method. If I do so I've the error `getClusterPresentation is not a function`.

I found a clue in [Different color to noise marker using here maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100832/different-color-to-noise-marker-using-here-maps), I tried

```
var clusterIcon = new window.H.clustering.DefaultTheme().getClusterPresentation(cluster).getIcon();
```

but it fails with the error `H.clustering.DefaultTheme is not a constructor`

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me. You can create a custom theme based on default theme. And then modify it.

Ref
[HERE Maps JS API v3: customize cluster marker's color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826080/here-maps-js-api-v3-customize-cluster-markers-color)

```
var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
    clusteringOptions: {
        eps: 2,
        minWeight: 3
    }
});

//default theme
var defaultTheme = clusteredDataProvider.getTheme();

//custom theme
var customTheme = {
    getClusterPresentation: function (cluster) {
        //Keep the default theme for clusters
        var clusterMarker = defaultTheme.getClusterPresentation.call(defaultTheme, cluster);
        return clusterMarker;
    },
    getNoisePresentation: function (noisePoint) {
        //get the default noise markers
        var noiseMarker = defaultTheme.getNoisePresentation.call(defaultTheme, noisePoint);
        //modify them here..
        //and return the custom marker (H.map.Marker)
        return noiseMarker;
    }
}

//set the custom theme
clusteredDataProvider.setTheme(customTheme);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to set the getNoisePresentation method after the H.clustering.Provider had been created. Do not set the theme property in the clustering provider constructor.

```
var clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {...});
clusteredDataProvider.getTheme().getNoisePresentation = function (noisePoint) { 
// return custom noisePoint marker here 
};
```

The default clustering icon remains but it will now use your custom noise icon.